Parsing 彼の優しさが一人の女の子へ向ける感情
The below is a monologue made by a speaker who happened to become more conscious of a guy close to her:

だってもう無意識に彼を目で追ってしまっている。かっこよく見えてしまっている。彼の優しさが一人の女の子へ向ける感情なのではないかと...

I have trouble making sense of 彼の優しさが一人の女の子へ向ける感情.
I am uncertain how should it be parsed: It is either understood as [彼の優しさが一人の女の子へ向ける]感情 (感情 modified by 彼の優しさが一人の女の子へ向ける) or [彼の優しさ]が[一人の女の子へ向ける感情] (彼の優しさ which is 一人の女の子へ向ける感情). I think the former makes sense.
Also, I am not sure what is the direct object for 向ける. I think it is 私: 彼の優しさが私を一人の女の子へ向ける感情?

一人の女の子へ向ける is a relative clause that modifies 感情, so the direct object of 向ける is 感情. Your second interpretation is correct. Here's the breakdown:

感情を一人の女の子へ向ける
to direct an emotion towards one girl
一人の女の子へ向ける感情
an emotion which [someone] directs towards one girl
→ a (kind of) emotion directed to a certain girl
(Of course, this is an euphemistic way of referring to "romantic interest")
彼の優しさは一人の女の子へ向ける感情なのだ
(It's that) his kindness is a kind of emotion directed to a certain girl
彼の優しさが一人の女の子へ向ける感情なのではないかと(思ってしまっている)...
(I can't help wondering if) his kindness could mean that he has that kind of emotion directed towards a certain girl...

